# Hash same value across different dataframes

Tags: r

My question is whether it is possible to have same value hashed/anonymized same way across multiple dataframes.

Lets assume that I got Classification column in two dataframes with entries of Executive, Director, Manager and I'd like to have Executive be Class1, Director Class2, Manager Class3 in both

If thats available for one column - can I apply it across all my dataframes, so it anonymize accurately any repetitions of data?

```
Table1 <- data.frame (ID = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3"), Color = c("Yellow","Pink", "Red"), Classification = c("Furniture", "Vehicle", "RTV"), Zone = c("Europe", "Asia", "America") )
Table2 <-data.frame (ID = c("ID1", "ID2"), Product = c("Product1", "Product2"),Color = c("Pink", "Red"))
Table3 <- data.frame (ID = c("ID2", "ID1", "ID3"), Grade = c("Excellent","Mediocre", "Good"), Classification = c("RTV", "Vehicle", "Furniture"), Zone = c("America", "Asia", "Europe") )
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, make a lookup table of the raw values and hashed values and apply it to both your data frames.

Comment: Assuming I have 30 columns to anonymize, do I need each column lookup? or it can be done via loop or pipes?

Comment: This isn't clear at all. Are the columns to anonymize all the same values? Or are the different keys for different columns? Please make a small reproducible example (2 or 3 columns to anonymize, 2 or 3 rows each) along with the desired output. Then we can demonstrate an answer with code rather than talk vaguely about something lacking specifics.

Comment: I've put a screenshot with some dummy data. I dont yet have the real data nevertheless and I just imagine how this should look like in advance, but I guess I am accurate with requirements

Answer (score 0):

```
my_classes <- c("Executive" = "Class1", "Director" = "Class2", "Secretary" = "Class3")

dat <- tibble(positions = c("Secretary", "Director", "Executive"))

# A tibble: 3 × 1
  positions
  <chr>    
1 Secretary
2 Director 
3 Executive


dat %>%
  mutate(class = str_replace_all(positions, my_classes))

  positions class 
  <chr>     <chr> 
1 Secretary Class3
2 Director  Class2
3 Executive Class1
```

Comment: Okay, it works but assuming I'd have like 30 columns across 5-6 datasets, then can I apply it somehow at ease?

Comment: Simplest way is to pivot_longer the columns and edit accordingly. Chuck up some sample data if you need more help.

Comment: ive put the simple example of what id like to achieve in question, also created 3 short tables to have the data to work on